# Display single list value in 2 different columns in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp

How can I display list value in two different columns according to ID's?

```
<div id="mappedORg">
  <table width="100%" id="myTable" class="sortable">
    <tr>
      <h1>Mapped Organization</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><strong><s:property value="getText('global.univeristy')" /></strong></th>
        <th ><strong><s:property value="getText('global.college')" /></strong></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <s:iterator value="userOrgMappedList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="style11" style="width: 20%;"><s:property  value="userOrgMappedList[#questat.index].OrgName"/></td>
      </s:iterator>
      </tr>
```

Here is my query for fetching university and college

```
SELECT UOM.Organization_ID, OM.Organization_Name, OM.Organization_Type_ID, UOM.Is_Active,OM.Organization_Parent_Id FROM T_User_Organization_Map UOM  
INNER JOIN M_Organization_Master OM ON UOM.Organization_ID = OM.Organization_ID 
INNER JOIN M_Organization_Type_Master OTM ON OM.Organization_Type_ID=OTM.Organization_Type_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN M_Organization_Master LOM ON OM.Organization_Parent_Id = LOM.Organization_ID WHERE UOM.User_ID IN (' 1 ')  AND OM.Is_Active = 1 ORDER BY OM.Organization_Name


Query is returing organization_parent_id as whose organization_id is university for that particular organization.
```

I want to display university and college in different column as different university has different college and all are fetching from same list 
usrOrgMapping .  How can I display all College with respect to university.
How can I perform this operation in jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different TD s in the loop inside TR

```
<s:iterator value="userOrgMappedList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="style11" style="width: 20%;"><s:property  value="userOrgMappedList[#questat.index].univeristy"/></td>
<td valign="top" class="style11" style="width: 20%;"><s:property  value="userOrgMappedList[#questat.index].OrgName"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: I used but there is condition all university has different colleges as userOrgMappedList have both university as well as college values and I am unable yo set condition like  (userOrgMappedList[#questat.index].org_parent_ID == userOrgMappedList[#questat.index].Org_ID) then next column will popup for colleges according to universiy. How can I implement this condition in jsp page

Comment: University and college are n same column of mysql database only type_ID is different for University it is '1' for college it is '2'.

Comment: you can use `group by` in the query itself to get universities with its colleges.

Comment: Can you please specify the query I am not getting how to use group by clause here

Comment: <s:if test="userOrgMappedChildList[#questat.index].OrgParentId ==userOrgMappedChildList[#questat.index].OrgId   ">

Comment: I am unable to use <s:if condition for 2 values of list